# Fetching data using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, ado

I have a function to retrieve all AccountName and Location from the Account table in database and store it in a Dictionary in ascending order of AccountName using LINQ query

A probable solution which I can think of using ADO is somewhat like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        string str = "Mumbai";
        Program ob = new Program();
        ob.DisplayCustomerByLocation(str);
    }
    
    public Dictionary<string,string> DisplayCustomerByLocation(string location){
        Dictionary<string,string> d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        string xyz = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlCon"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(xyz);
        using(conn){
            string q = "select AccountName, Location from Account where Location=@location order by AccountName asc";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q,conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location",location);
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(rd.Read()){
                string name = rd[0].ToString();
                string loc = rd[1].ToString();
                d.Add(name,loc);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong!
Now I wanna achieve this using LINQ query, somewhat like this maybe

(from temp in Account where temp.Location==the_location_variable order by temp.AccountName select temp.AccountName, temp.Location).ToDictionary();

Can anyone help out in writing this function correctly? Any suggestions will be of immense help! Thank you!

Comment: If you want to use Linq, you should add a linq provider that will translate to SQL. The most common choice is Entity Framework and there are hundreds of tutorials on the web.

Comment: Check out a program called [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) (or similar program), it will be very helpful as you start to learn and develop your LINQ skills.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using Entity Framework Core 5, C#9.

```
public partial class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Code in a console application. I did another version with a SortedDictionary but see nothing truly gained.

```
namespace AccountsToDictionaryEfCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "ToDictionary";
            
            Version1();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Version1()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            Dictionary<string, string> results = context.Account
                .OrderBy(account => account.AccountName)
                .ToDictionary(_ => _.AccountName, _ => _.Location);

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{result.Key}, {result.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- As mentioned in comments there are plenty of resources on Stackoverflow and other sites to make an informed decision on which direction to take.
- [Enumerable.ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0) documentation
- if new to Entity Framework check out [EF Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) to [reverse engineer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) your database. Also take time to read up on Entity Framework such as in this [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/11/25/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core-5/).